# add vs update in set operations in python - in case of String

Tags: python, set

**I am new to python**, When I am trying to add or update the `String` element in `set` it's behaving strangely.

```
dummySet={10,20,30}
type(dummySet)
<class 'set'>
dummySet.add('Adam')
{10, 20, 30, 'Adam'}#Here it is adding a whole word, when I do add operation.
dummySet.update('Eve')
{'E', 10, 'Adam', 20, 'e', 'v', 30}#It is adding all character as element in the set.
```

I had tried over the google also but havn't got the clear explanation on this.

Can any one explain why this is behaving or reason behind this.

Comment: `.update` takes a iterable and adds all the items in the iterable. `.add` takes a single item and adds it to the set. `str` objects are iterable

Comment: try dummySet.update( ['Eve'] )

Comment: @RedCricket In that they are trying to access the integer type.

Comment: The explanation is the same.

Comment: @coldspeed @Red Cricket @juanpa.arrivillaga As per the explanation the argument has to be hashables, but here in `add` and `update` method it will be hashables, so how it's behaving differently. Please explain the difference because that clarity is not present with the respect of `String`. If you can't then remove the duplicate flag from this question.

Comment: As I explained in my first comment, update exprects  an *iterable*